# Connect external application with my Salesforce app

Tags: rest-api, appexchange, authentication

We are developing an external application which will connect to a Salesforce app (also being developed by us) for data integration.

Now this Salesforce app can be installed by any organization, so I am wondering what do I need to do for initial setup to connect my external application with this Salesforce app.

In the external application, there is a salesforce connection screen, where there will be UserName/ Password box. Do I also need to enter ClientId/ Secret in the same screen? If not, how will these be fetched for REST calls?

Comment: [Understanding Authentication](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_authentication.htm) is a good start.

Comment: I understand authentication but question is from a client's perspective. They do not understand ClientID/Secret thing. They only know username and password. So is there a way I can obtain ClientID/Secret using API or is it going to manual step?

Comment: The external application you're developing will need to send client id and secret, they are not entered by the user. Moreover, your only choice of oAuth grant type is authorization code (aka Web Server flow in SF universe).